# How to put some information and export a table into same .txt file in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I know I could export an array into a table form by

```
n={{1,3,3},{4,5,6}}
Export["file.txt",n,"Table"]
```

But how do I write some information before exporting the table to the same file?
I know I could write information by something like:

```
x=37
stmp = OpenWrite["file.txt"]
WriteString[stmp, "E=", x, "\n"];
Close[stmp]
```

But putting table into the same file will erase previous information: E=37
Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Welcome to the StackExchange network! You can consider asking Mathematica-related questions on [Mathematica.SE](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/) in the future for better answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply pass the stream name (`stmp`) to `Export`, like this:

```
stmp = OpenWrite["file.txt"]
WriteString[stmp, "E=", x, "\n"]
Export[stmp,n,"Table"]
Close[stmp]
```